# JQuery DatePicker Working Intermittently

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the **JQuery DatePicker** plugin for my ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application. I have used the DatePicker alot of times previously in other applications without any trouble.

However, I have come across an issue in my current app, whereby, the JQuery DatePicker works only intermittently. What I mean by this is, for example, I have the following JavaScript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Equal Opps
    $('#DOB').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1900:2030" });


});
```

This file is referenced in my Razor View (along with all the other files needed to make DatePicker work) and then I have the following TextBox which once clicked on, the DatePicker should pop up.

```
<div class="editor-field sepH_b">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
</div>
```

However, sometimes when the page loads and I click on the TextBox, the DatePicker pops up, if I refresh the page and click on the TextBox again, the DatePicker won't work, if I then refresh again and click on the TextBox, the DatePicker then works ???

Sometimes when I load the page for the 1st time, the DatePicker will not work at all.

I really have no solution to what is going on here. Maybe it is a caching issue, but I really don't know.

Please could someone help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle where this behaviour is reproducable?

Comment: @mightyuhu Sorry, I've no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through my code in a bit more detail, I realised that in the **head** section of my Master Layout page, I was referencing various JQuery scripts. I forgot that these scripts were already referenced here, yet I was still referencing them again in other pages throughout my site. I removed the duplicated references and everything seems to be working as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are linking the jquery js files correctly. I faced similar issue, when I was referencing them locally. On checking the broswer error console, I found that the `jquery-ui` file was not being loaded properly.

Use the google hosting links for [jquery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) and [jquery-ui](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui).

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion wasn't the problem but it helped put me on the correct path to fix the issue.